# How do I change the size of multiple subplots and add a main title?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
y = x ** 2

# First plot
plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot(y, label='x**2')
plt.plot(x ** 3, label='x**3')
plt.title('default axes ranges')
plt.legend(loc = 2)
plt.ylim(0,120)
plt.xlim(0,5)

# Second plot
plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot(y, label='x**2')
plt.plot(x ** 3, label='x**3')
plt.title('tight axes')
plt.legend(loc = 2)
plt.ylim(0,120)
plt.xlim(0,5)

# Third plot
plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(y, label='x**2')
plt.plot(x ** 3, label='x**3')
plt.title('custom axes range')
plt.legend(loc = 1)
plt.ylim(0,60)
plt.xlim(2.0,5.0);
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:
[image]

How do I change the size so it matches the second photo? Also, how do I add a main title?

```
plt.title('multiple plots')
```

The above command does not work. It does not show up in the output.

Comment: I've edited your other questions. Please use the [tag:python] tag when asking python questions and please use code formatting for all code, not quotation blocks.

Comment: You're also asking multiple questions at once. Focus on a single question at a time and please look up your questions before asking them. Your title question was easily found by searching "matplotlib title for all subplots". Your other question is not clear but appears to be an aspect ratio or figure size question.

Comment: To change the figure size you can use the [`set_size_inches`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches) method, e.g., `fig = plt.gcf()  # get the current figure object` then `fig.set_size_inches(10, 3)`, which in that case will produce a figure 10 inches wide and 3 inches high.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

1-you can use `plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))` to open a figure before wrtiting to it. this way you can adjust the size of the figure to your desire and for title you need `plt.suptitle("title")`.

2- you can simply use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncolumns, figsize=(x, y))`. this will return one figure and multiple axes, so you can refer to them like `ax[row_num][column_num]` and then use that axis methods to draw. for your code it will be like:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
y = x ** 2

# First plot
fig, ax = subplots(1, 3, figsize(15, 5))
ax[0].plot(y, label='x**2')
ax[0].plot(x ** 3, label='x**3')
ax[0].set_title('default axes ranges')
ax[0].legend(loc = 2)
ax[0].set_ylim(0, 120)
ax[0].set_xlim(0, 5)

# Second plot
ax[1].plot(y, label='x**2')
ax[1].plot(x ** 3, label='x**3')
ax[1].set_title('tight axes')
ax[1].legend(loc = 2)
ax[1].set_ylim(0, 120)
ax[1].set_xlim(0, 5)

# Third plot
ax[2].plot(y, label='x**2')
ax[2].plot(x ** 3, label='x**3')
ax[2].set_title('custom axes range')
ax[2].legend(loc = 2)
ax[2].set_ylim(0, 60)
ax[2].set_xlim(2, 5)
fig.suptitle("mutiple plots")
plt.show()
```

Comment: suptitle is called sgtitle in matlab...